# Insert *.prn files in Latex

Tags: graphics, eps, epstopdf

I'm trying to export some graphs from Excel by printing them as *.prn files. I can't find an option for *.eps in Excel.

But the question is... Is there any way to include *.prn images/plots in LateX?

Paul

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/31128/how-do-i-convert-a-prn-file-to-pdf

Comment: Recent versions of excel have pdf export anyway, which provides a more direct route

Answer (score 1):

If you use `latex` (as opposed to `pdflatex`), you can only include EPS files.

If you use `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex`, the image formats supported are

> PNG, JPEG, PDF, EPS

the last one via (automatic) conversion to PDF when `pdflatex` or `lualatex` are used. Actually `xelatex` supports also some other formats via the QuickTime library on Mac OS X (and possibly on other platforms).

There is no single PRN format, as explained at [this question in SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/questions/31128/how-do-i-convert-a-prn-file-to-pdf).

There are Windows utilities that allow printing to PDF files and you should use one of these.